# Making a hierarchical (MultiIndex) or pivot from data with many rows per date

Tags: python, pandas

How can I best format data that has multiple "levels" per time/date into a pandas DataFrame?

e.g. (CSV data from http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Regional_Summary_Data.csv)

[image]

In this case, each date has one higher-level ("BC"), then one step lower ("All/Fraser/Interior..."), then the final granularity ("All/Fraser East/Fraser North..."), then values at the final granularity. What would be a good way to organize this in a DataFrame? I could reduce the data to just "Date"/"Final region"/Value, but this does not preserve the hierarchy.

If I use pivot tables, I lose the granularity (I would need to apply an aggregating function). I would like to first put this into a DataFrame that I can later perform aggregating functions on.

I tried `.stack()`, which correctly created one hierarchy for each date, but turns it into a Series object:

```
Date                      
2020-01-29  Province                     BC
            HA                       Fraser
            HSDA                Fraser East
            Cases_Reported                0
            Province                     BC
                                  ...      
2021-04-22  Cases_Reported               16
            Province          Out of Canada
            HA                Out of Canada
            HSDA              Out of Canada
            Cases_Reported                0
Length: 34200, dtype: object
```

I considered creating tuples like in the example here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object

but creating tuples for each date does not seem idiomatic. Is there functionality within pandas I can use instead of defining the MultiIndex manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output in text form?

Comment: @Utsav data can be found here: http://www.bccdc.ca/Health-Info-Site/Documents/BCCDC_COVID19_Regional_Summary_Data.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to lose granularity when using a pivot-table. `DataFrame.pivot` reshapes the data without aggregation. You just have to decide what is an index (row levels) and what is a column (column levels). In your case you might want the provinces/subprovinces as an index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw = pd.read_csv(file, sep=",")

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 20)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 10)
pd.set_option("display.width", 200)

df = pd.pivot(raw, columns=[], index=['Date','Province', 'HA','HSDA'], values=['Cases_Reported', 'Cases_Reported_Smoothed'])

print(df)
```

Which gives you this output:

```
                                                                    Cases_Reported  Cases_Reported_Smoothed
Date       Province      HA               HSDA                                                             
2020-01-29 BC            All              All                                  0.0                     0.00
                         Fraser           All                                  0.0                     0.00
                                          Fraser East                          0.0                     0.00
                                          Fraser North                         0.0                     0.00
                                          Fraser South                         0.0                     0.00
...                                                                            ...                      ...
2021-04-22 BC            Vancouver Island All                                 23.0                    32.43
                                          Central Vancouver Island             5.0                     8.71
                                          North Vancouver Island               2.0                     4.00
                                          South Vancouver Island              16.0                    19.71
           Out of Canada Out of Canada    Out of Canada                        0.0                     0.43
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right that `pivot` does not perform aggregation (pivot_table does). What I don't understand is why `columns` can be supplied as an empty list. According to the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) `columns` are "used to make the new frame's columns", and `columns` is not optional. So why not specify `columns=["Cases_Reported", "Cases_Reported_Smoothed"]`?

Comment: If you pass the values as columns you create two-level multi-index columns with no values in the table. The entries of the values parameter make up the lowest level of the column index, this is why the columns can be empty if there is no need for more levels.